# Copy a dirty branch for a new branch keeping it

Tags: git

I have a branch with several changes and I would like to copy its content for a new branch. That's new branch essencially would have the same content, maybe a little less. So, **is it possible to copy a dirty branch for a new or another branch keeping this one?**

Comment: @DurgpalSingh, it is not duplicated. My question is about local branch.

Comment: Alderath is correct, there is no such thing as a "dirty branch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding something about how git works. Each branch is only a pointer to a specific commit.

There is no such thing as a dirty branch. You are probably thinking about the case when you have a branch checked out, and you have a dirty work-tree. (This means that you have made changes to your work-tree, which have not yet been committed). But the branch is not dirty. The work-tree is dirty.

The **only** way you could save something **on** a branch is to commit it. If you don't push the branch, just creating a temporary commit could be okay:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "tmp commit"
git checkout -b new_branch
git reset HEAD^     #this will reset the branch pointer to the previous commit,
                    #but keep the work-tree
```

And when you want to go back to the original branch and restore the dirty worktree:

```
git checkout original_branch
git reset HEAD^
```

---

Alternatively, you could save the changes in the stash. This is probably the preferred solution:

```
git add -A
git stash --keep-index
git checkout -b new_branch
```

And when you want to go back to the original branch and restore the dirty worktree:

```
git checkout original_branch
git stash pop
```

Comment: Why `git reset HEAD^`, not `git reset HEAD` ?

Comment: `git reset HEAD` and `git reset HEAD^` mean different things.

`HEAD` is the latest commit on the current branch. `^` means "the previous commit". Since we made a temporary commit on the branch, we want to reset to the commit before the latest commit (we want to get rid of the temporary commit which we used temporarily, only to store the changes).

Generally, you should probably prefer the second method of stashing though. This use case is basically what stashing is meant for. I just added the first example to show what you need to do to store the changes **on the original_branch**.

Answer (score 3):

What about?

`git checkout -b <new-branch>`

Comment: Arpit, in this way my dirty branch is keeped?

Comment: once new branch created, delete the dirty branch `git branch -D <dirty-branch>`

Comment: Arpit, nooo, I want keep it ;)

Comment: @GeisonSantos if you want to keep it, then running the command mentioned in answer is good enough.